# How to find anything equivalent as R poppler in Debian?

Tags: debian, software-installation, r

I am trying to reproduce the proposal of the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33235038/54964), to get the amount of pages in a pdf document by R, but I cannot install R poppler in Debian 8.5 as root

```
> install.packages("Rpoppler")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'https://cran.wu.ac.at/src/contrib/Rpoppler_0.0-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'unknown' length 38208 bytes (37 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 37 KB

* installing *source* package ‘Rpoppler’ ...
** package ‘Rpoppler’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking whether pkg-config knows about poppler-glib >= 0.18.0... no
configure: error: cannot determine poppler-glib compile/link flags
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rpoppler’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rpoppler’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpwShV17/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("Rpoppler") :
  installation of package ‘Rpoppler’ had non-zero exit status
> install.packages("Rpoppler::PDF_info")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
package ‘Rpoppler::PDF_info’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)
```

R: 3.3.2
OS: Debian 8.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> configure: error: cannot determine poppler-glib compile/link flags

It looks like the [dependencies](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rpoppler/index.html) have not been installed:

```
SystemRequirements: Poppler Glib interface headers and libraries () 
                   [Debian/Ubuntu: libpoppler-glib-dev, Fedora: poppler-glib-devel]
```

After installing via `apt-get`, the `Rpoppler` package should compile. Oh, and the hint from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33235038/2303098) works just fine:

```
> Rpoppler::PDF_info("/usr/share/doc/cvs/cvs.pdf")$Pages
[1] 194
```

Comment: It seems that `apt-get install libpoppler-glib-dev` as root is sufficient. Then, `install.packages(Rpoppler)`. Confirmed, then you get `> Rpoppler::PDF_info("/usr/share/doc/cvs/cvs.pdf")$Pages [1] 194`.